When did android start supporting versioned library?
I have heard in the past that Android doesn't support versioned libraries and all library names and SONAMEs should end with the extension .so. Libtool disables version suffixed SONAMEs and library files for the same reason.
But many libraries in Termux have version suffixed SONAMEs and programs can load them without any problem.
So when did android start supporting versioned library names?
